# Debugging LiPo charging circuit with TP4056/ FS312

Tags: battery-charging, charging, lipo

I'm building a desktop soldering fan including a rechargeable battery.
Unfortunately the battery is not charging and voltage stays the same (3,76V, tested for 60min)

Battery is a LiPo cell with 1500mAh, I'm using a tp4056 and a FS312F-G for the power circuit.

In addition:

With USB Power and battery attached, the fan runs as expected, measurements read:
Fan output: 12,2V/ 10mA

With Battery only attached:
Fan output: 12,2V/ 64mA

Is there something wrong in my schematic? How can I further debug the circuit?

[image: BMS circuit]
[image: Complete circuit]

Comment: Schematic shows a short between Gate of one FET and Source of the other FET of the FS8205. Is this real?

Comment: You are right, will fix the short and report back if it's working. Is there anything else that you can identify?

Comment: I solved the short and also connected GND of the FS312 to Bat(-). The battery now is charging correctly, however when turning it on (connect Vout and Voutin), the fan won't turn when battery is connected but only with USB power. Do you have any addition idea @BruceAbbott Thanks ahead!

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the updated schematic (short removed, etc.) and updated problem.